# Как подключиться к серверу из локальной сети по внешнему ip?

Tags: apache, apache-modules

У меня есть замечательно работающий apache сервер, к нему и с локалки и из интернета подключиться можно, никаких проблем, порты проброшены. И с моим вебсокетом в локалке он тоже ладит.

Но появилась жёсткая необходимость, чтобы моя локальная сеть получала доступ к серверу через внешний ip. Виной тому стал mod_proxy_wstunnel, который, видимо, устанавливает соединение с локальным сокетом через внешнее подключение, т.к. когда я подключаюсь к моим вебсокетам через сервер из интернета я всегда получаю ту же ошибку, как если бы я пытался подключиться к своему локальному серверу через внешний ip, для этого я специально создавал ситуации с разными ошибками.

Что для этого нужно сделать?

Мой единственный хост:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@diskyp
    DocumentRoot "D:/XAMPP/htdocs/site"
    ServerName serv
    ErrorLog "logs/serv-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/serv-access.log" common
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia On 
    SSLProxyEngine on
    <Proxy *>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://127.0.0.1:8080/chat
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://127.0.0.1:8080/chat
    Header set Connection "upgrade"
    Header set Upgrade "websocket"
</VirtualHost>
```

В httpd.conf `ServerName localhost:80` и `Listen *:80`, больше, я полагаю, там ничего интересного.

Comment: VPN туннель поднимайте, между внешкой и сервером.

Comment: @And, у вас есть какие-нибудь рекомендации по этому поводу? Средствами apache никак не решить мою проблему? Первый гайд на который я наткнулся - установка openVPN https://habrahabr.ru/post/233971/ , но когда я уже 20 секунд пытался проскроллить эту статью до конца я начал волноваться. Есть какое-нибудь супер короткое и эффективное руководство по запуску VPN?

Comment: Ну варианты разные, попробуйте почитать про Site-to-site VPN (IPSec).  Вообще сначала лучше начать с Основ межсетевого обмена в сетях TCP/IP. Вообще тема по VPN довольно не маленькая, если хотите разобраться вам придется это читать и вникать, тут в двух словах не расскажешь у всех могут быть разные настройки и соображения по этому поводу, а вообще лучше быть сисадмином :)

Comment: @And, не, я слишком ленив для этого всего, мне нужно пошаговое руководство типа скачай->открой файл->исправь строчку->запусти, это было бы идеально.

Comment: наймите сисадмина.

Comment: @And, я не для того вопросы задаю на этом ресурсе, чтобы в итоге нанимать кого-то. Я хочу сделать всё сам, но максимально простым и рациональным путём.

Comment: вы противоречите сами себе, хочу сам, но ленюсь, никого не найму, сам сделаю. Ну сделайте тогда через SSL туннель и потом юзайте openVPN, - либо изучите тему TCP/IP и сделайте VPN канал, который организуется с использованием VPN клиент cisco, - либо используйте схему Site-to-site VPN (IPSec), - либо GRE-over-IPSec. - варианты истекают. Если вы не хотите изучать, то тут как бы уже нонсенс.

Comment: Внешний ip на роутере? Это очень не тривиальная задача. И вряд ли реализуемая на произвольном оборудовании. Проще заставить mod_proxy_wstunnel работать с локальным адресом. Может Вы с ним просто не разобрались?